# Texts that combine topology and logic

Tags: general-topology, logic, reference-request

I am currently very interested in texts, books, and papers that combine topology and logic. I recall reading many years ago a journal article that talked about both topology and the axiom of choice. I would be very glad to see some references.

Comment: That seems very vague. Maybe you can give us some sense of your level of knowledge in these two areas?

Comment: This is far too open-ended. A simple google search yields countless results. In order to be appropriate for MSE I think this question needs much more focus.

Comment: There's a very famous textbook by Steven Vickers, [Topology via Logic](https://www.amazon.com/Topology-Cambridge-Theoretical-Computer-Science/dp/0521576512) which talks about the relationship between (intuitionistic) propositional logic and topology (via frames). This is an excellent primer for a book on [Topos Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topos), which gives a souped up version of the same relationship, now between (intuitionistic) predicate logic and topology (via topoi).